# Использование Cookie при работе с HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, cookie, htmlagilitypack

С помощью [SimpleBrowser](https://github.com/SimpleBrowserDotNet/SimpleBrowser) заполняю поля логина и пароля и имитирую нажатие кнопки, после чего происходит вход на сайт. Далее из объекта извлекаю файлы с Cookie в `CookieContainer`, после чего хочу начать парсинг с помощью HtmlAgilityPack. Как использовать Cookie при парсинге, чтобы оставаться авторизованным?

Авторизация и извлечение cookies:

```
Browser browser = new Browser
{
    UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10"
};

browser.Navigate(url);

if (LastRequestFailed(browser))
    return;

browser.Find("email").Value = "***";
browser.Find("pass").Value = "***";
browser.Find(ElementType.Button, "id", "u_0_2").Click();

CookieContainer cookies = browser.Cookies;
```

Тут говорю, что необходимо использовать cookies:

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb {UseCookies = true};
// как их сюда поместить?
```

Comment: @AK код приложил

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb {UseCookies = true};
htmlWeb.PreRequest += request =>
{
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    return true;
};
```